# selecting multiple row values when column value is same

Tags: sql

I new and my SQL knowledge is very basic. I am starting to learn.

I would like to know how can I select different row values only when the column values is the same:

Through all OrderIDs I would like to find only cases where an OrderID have 2 differents UserID

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thank you very much for the help and FYI I am using Exasol.

Nice to meet you all

JD

Comment: What did you already try? Please add your code. And please add the table structure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Several possible solutions. GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) >= 2 is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly but do you mean this?

I assume your table looks like this

+---------+--------+
| OrderID | UserID |
+---------+--------+
| Order1  | UserA  |
+---------+--------+
| Order1  | UserB  |
+---------+--------+

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The HAVING clause looks for orders with 2 users.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you VERY VERY much for your help and sorry that my question was not clear enough for you

I anyway did manage to extract what was needed with your help.

SELECT OrderID, COUNT(UserID)

FROM

(

select   UserID 
        ,OrderID

from mytable

group by 1,2

)

GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(distinct UserID) >= 2

;

THANK YOU

JD